# Simplify-scorm window.open(scormUrl)

Tags: scorm

I am trying to open my SCORM education in a new window but when i do, all the reporting stops working (The same goes if i do it in an iframe).
When i just do location.href = scormURL; then it works fine. My scorm file is in a different domain then the LMS.

It seems like the SCORM api doesn't get initialized after doing loadFromJSON(response) on my scorm response. But this problem only occurs when i open in a new window or show the scorm education in an iframe.

I use SCORM2004.

EDIT:
It was XSS problem and it was solved by routing to azure CDN via ocelot gateway to get the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My scorm file is in a different domain then the LMS.

This is your problem.

The only link the SCORM package has to your LMS (and therefore to your reporting) is the [SCORM API](https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/). Modern browsers do not allow  [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (cross-origin resource sharing) by default because it opens you to [XSS](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-0-never-insert-untrusted-data-except-in-allowed-locations) (cross-site scripting) attacks.

The package may be able to [find the API](https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/api-discovery-algorithms/) if one exists on the external domain, but it will not be able to communicate with the LMS directly.

The way I worked around this was to add a wrapper `.js` file on the external domain that hosted the SCORM API and used [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to pass calls back to the LMS.

You then use `window.open` or your `iframe` to open a page on the external domain which has access to `scorm_wrapper.js` and its own `iframe` that hosts your package.

---

## scorm_wrapper.js

Because the [`Window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) method is not reliable and not fully-featured when the current `window` was opened from a different origin, we will use the domain directly.

Since we control the LMS, we know the domain it is running on and since we just opened the package, we know it should be active. We can `postMessage` it to ask for a reply.

```
function receiveMessage(data) { 
    // We will return to this later...
};

// Be ready for the reply from the LMS.
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage(event));

// Ping the domain your LMS is running on.
window.parent.postMessage('ping', 'https://example.com');
```

When our LMS receives the message, it should reply with a `postMessage` of its own to `event.origin` which is the domain our package is running on.

Now when we get the reply from the LMS, we know we have access.

```
var connected = false;

function receiveMessage(data) {
    // ...

    // Do not do anything unless the message was from
    // a domain we trust.
    if (event.origin !== 'https://example.com') return;

    switch (event.data) {
        case 'pong':
            connected = true;
            break;
        // We will return to this later...
    }
}
```

Now any time the wrapper's API object gets called from the package, we can pass the message on to the LMS.

```
function sendMessage(args) {
    if (!connected) return;
    window.parent.postMessage(args, 'https://example.com');
}

const apiWrapper = {
    Initialize: function (args) {
        sendMessage({ method: 'Initialize', data: args });
    },
    // More SCORM endpoints...
};

window.API = apiWrapper;
window.API_1484_11 = apiWrapper;
```

Add cases to `receiveMessage` as needed.

```
function receiveMessage(data) {
    // ...
    switch (event.data) {
        case 'pong':
            connected = true;
            break;
        case 'initialize-acknowledge`:
            //...
            break;
    }
}
```

---

This approach isn't great, but it gets you around a cross-domain issue safely and without needing access to server configurations.

Comment: Thanks alot for this good response, i have been trying to get it to work but i am not getting all the way.. 
The ping from the SCORM package goes to the LMS but when i am ponging back from the LMS to the SCORM package that message doens't get through.

Comment: Any chance you would be able to post your full solution html and the js for the api and wrapper?

Comment: @bgrantdev Unfortunately, no. Feel free to ask a new question and ping me, though.

Comment: I am getting the cross domain problem when the scorm is attempting to grab the API in the first place.  LMS side is housing the content in an  iframe on a simple html page.  SCORM version 1.2, I have little control over the contents of the package, users will  be creating the courses in Articulate and uploading to a CDN,  but full control on the LMS side.

Comment: I’ll probably need more information about your current setup to offer help. Please ask a question including how your system works right now and the errors you’re getting and I’ll check it out.